# print garbage value in c

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

what i was trying to do is to count  the number of alphanumerics and im using pointers .
everything is working fine but when im trying to print the values its printing what i wanted + garbage values because of the continuation of the memory it holds

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <ctype.h>

 #define SIZE 10000 

 void printChar(int *p);

 int main(){

int *p,*new_p;
int c,i = 0,numOfAlNum = 0,numOfChar = 0;

p = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int));

/*If memory cannot be allocated*/
if(p == NULL){
    printf("Error! memory not allocated\n");
    exit(0);
}
else
    printf("Memory successfully allocated\n");


printf("enter something\n");


while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){

    *(p + i) = c;
    i++;
    /*Add Realloc to the loop*/
    new_p = realloc(p,(i+1)*sizeof(int));
    
    /*check for ability to allocate new memory*/
    if(new_p == NULL){
        printf("Error! memory not allocated\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        p = new_p;  
    }
    
    /*Check is alphanumeric*/
    if(isalnum(c)){
        numOfAlNum++;
    }
    
    numOfChar++;    
}


printf("The output is: \n");
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    printf("%s",(p+i));
}
printf("\nNumber of Characters is %d\n",numOfChar);
printf("Number of Alpha-Numeric is %d\n",numOfAlNum);


 return 0;

}
```

EXAMPLE OF Expected OUTPUT : "hello world"  WHAT IM GETTING IS: "hello world&^^^%^#"
how do i get rid of the unnecessary values at the end ?

Comment: Look at your code and ask yourself: "Where do I ensure that any string I'm building is properly terminated?" More unusual, why are you building an `int` array, then sending it to `printf` as `%s` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig when Iv tried using char*malloc(SIZE*sizof(char)) i didnt get the output so i tried with an int , and Im just starting to learn c and may write unexplained stuff this is why im asking for help (:

Comment: Terminated string are covered in any C text. I suggest you get a good book. Regarding your code, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/enj8novfr) is most likely what you're trying to do, but you're not going to get there from websites and quick-how-to's. It's going to take good reference materials, and a LOT of practice and time. Best of luck.

Comment: U need to use %d for int as printf format specifier so this should u try `printf("%d",*(p+i))` also u need some sort of count of already assigned characters and print only that count number of characters or fill with memset 0red all the SIZE elements after allocating.

Comment: @user786 Printing an `int` with `"%c"` is a fine alternative to `"%d"`.  The `int` value is converted to an `unsigned char` and the corresponding character is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do i get rid of the unnecessary values at the end ?

Rather than print to the size of the allocation `SIZE`,
print the portion of the allocation that was assigned:  `numOfChar`.

Use `"%c"` to print individual characters.
`"%s"` is for *strings*: *null character* terminated character arrays.

```
//for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
//  printf("%s",(p+i));
//}

for(j = i; i < numOfChar; i++){
  printf("%c",(p+i));
}
```